# Notification on table change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr-hub

I want to send notification when ApplyLeave table changes.Scenerio is like...
when user applies for a leave the manager will get a notification that "Some one has applied for a leave".I am struggling on How to accomplish this.I am using code first and SignalR to send the notification.I am not good in javascript.Thanks in advance.

My ApplyLeave class

```
 public class ApplyLeave

{
      public long? EmployeeId { get; set; }
      public long? EmployeeLeaveTypesId { get; set; }
      public bool Approved { get; set; }
      public bool ViewedByManager { get; set; }
      public string ManagerRemark { get; set; }
}
```

My notification class

```
public class NotificationHub:Hub
    {

        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
        }
    }
```

in the view i have a button whose id="notify" .On clicking the button a i am saving data with ajax reques.On the ajax success event i need send a notification to the manager....I really have no idea of how to do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function ()
    {
 $('#notify').click(function () {

        var params = {
            "ViewByManager": $('#viewbymanager').val(),
            "ManagerRemark": $('#managerremark').val()
        };

        var dataToPost = JSON.stringify(params);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ApplyLeave/Apply",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dataToPost,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, textStatus){

 var  notification = $.connection.notificationHub; 
                    // send notification to the manager

                },

            });

        });
       });
        </script>
```

Comment: am i doing something wrong?Just point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you see the chat tutorial, you can apply the same logic here.
[here is the tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

I think what you can do is,

```
//send the user name to the server to broadcast to the connected client.
notification.send(user_name_whois_applying, some_msg);
```

And in the manager's view,

```
//connect to the same hub and call the client method.

$(function () {
    var notification = $.connection.notificationHub; ;
    notification.addNewMessageToPage= onAddMessage;

    $.connection.hub.start();
});
function onAddMessage(message) {
    // Add the message to somewhere
     $('#messages').append( message);
}
```

i think this should at least let you get going :)